# glmer model Error in list2env(data) : first argument must be a named list

Tags: error-handling

I'm really new to R and creating models so this may be an easy fix.

I am using glmer in the lme4 package to model my data:
    `B1 <- glmer(Overlap_M ~  1 + Sex_M + FieldSeason_M +(1|BirdID_M) ,data = OverlapDataFrame_matrix, family=Gamma, start=NULL)`

Each of my fixed effects and my random effect (BirdID_M) have been defined as.list created from the columns of the matrix 
    `"OverlapDataFrame_matrix"`

```
 `head(OverlapDataFrame_matrix)
     BirdID FieldSeason Sex  Overlap      Area
[1,]      1      5.2014   1 31.56543 118216.40
[2,]      2      5.2014   1 28.44252  74989.85
[3,]      3      5.2014   1  3.15136  30234.26
[4,]      4      5.2014   1 54.28696  33223.01
[5,]      5      5.2014   1  0.00000  55337.15
[6,]      6      5.2014   1 43.80645  21412.06`
```

When I run this model I get the error:
    `Error in list2env(data) : first argument must be a named list`

I have tried different ways to change the environment each variable is in, but I am not clear on how that works. Is that the issue here, or is there an easier fix?

Comment: this isn't entirely clear.  Could we have a reproducible example please?  I'm not at all clear on how your `_M` variables differ from the variables in the data frame, and why ...

Comment: ... in particular, I'm not sure why you're using `as.list()` on the columns??

Answer (score 2):

The lmer command needs your data input defined as data.frame

```
OverlapDataFrame_matrix <- data.frame(OverlapDataFrame_matrix)
```